# "find: paths must precede expression:" How do I specify a recursive search that also finds files in the current directory?

Tags: linux, bash, find

I am having a hard time getting **find** to look for matches in the current directory as well as its subdirectories.

When I run `find *test.c` it only gives me the matches in the current directory. (does not look in subdirectories)

If I try `find . -name *test.c` I would expect the same results, but instead it gives me only matches that are in a subdirectory. When there are files that should match in the working directory, it gives me: `find: paths must precede expression: mytest.c`

What does this error mean, and how can I get the matches from both the current directory and its subdirectories?

Comment: for the record, `find` of [msysgit](https://msysgit.github.io/) may throw this error unless you surround the pattern with quotes: `find . -name "*test.c"`. (In case you choose to prefer it over Windows' different [`find.exe`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725655%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and use from cmd)

Answer (score 496, accepted):

Try putting it in quotes -- you're running into the shell's wildcard expansion, so what you're acually passing to find will look like:

```
find . -name bobtest.c cattest.c snowtest.c
```

...causing the syntax error. So try this instead:

```
find . -name '*test.c'
```

Note the single quotes around your file expression -- these will stop the shell (bash) expanding your wildcards.

Comment: By way of example, you can see what's happening if you do `echo *test.c` ... the result won't be echo expanding the wildcard, but the shell itself. The simple lesson is if you're using wildcards, quote the filespec :-)

Comment: Thanks for helping me with this VARIANT.  I tried `find . -type f -printf ‘%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %p\n’` as found on the web, and was met with "paths must precede expression".  Problem was the quote marks were too "smart".  I retyped the command, causing the quotes to be replaced, and it ran.

Comment: For some reason single quotes didn't work for me. I had to use double quotes. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: single quotes for wildcard searches worked with Busybox & GNU `find` - if using a wildcard `*.$variable` you need double quotes.

Comment: @Planky: I put : find , -name 'write.lock' in shell script file but it has this error message. But if I type in console, it works. Anyone knows why?

Comment: You may aslo escape the `*` with a backslash '\' as stated by other users here. A helpful guide about the _notorious_ `find` can be found [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/calish-find-087766.html)

Answer (score 35):

What's happening is that the shell is expanding "*test.c" into a list of files.  Try escaping the asterisk as:

```
find . -name \*test.c
```

Comment: #gitbash this was the solution for me with git bash on windows, even when quoting the PATTERN `find . -name '*txt'`

Answer (score 26):

From find manual:

```
NON-BUGS         

   Operator precedence surprises
   The command find . -name afile -o -name bfile -print will never print
   afile because this is actually equivalent to find . -name afile -o \(
   -name bfile -a -print \).  Remember that the precedence of -a is
   higher than that of -o and when there is no operator specified
   between tests, -a is assumed.

   “paths must precede expression” error message
   $ find . -name *.c -print
   find: paths must precede expression
   Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D ... [path...] [expression]

   This happens because *.c has been expanded by the shell resulting in
   find actually receiving a command line like this:
   find . -name frcode.c locate.c word_io.c -print
   That command is of course not going to work.  Instead of doing things
   this way, you should enclose the pattern in quotes or escape the
   wildcard:
   $ find . -name '*.c' -print
   $ find . -name \*.c -print
```

Answer (score 22):

Try putting it in quotes:

```
find . -name '*test.c'
```

Answer (score 8):

I see this question is already answered. I just want to share what worked for me. I was missing a space between `(` and `-name`. So, the correct way of chosen files with excluding some of them would be like below;

```
find . -name 'my-file-*' -type f -not \( -name 'my-file-1.2.0.jar' -or -name 'my-file.jar' \)
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across this question when I was trying to find multiple filenames that I could not combine into a regular expression as described in @Chris J's answer, here is what worked for me

```
find . -name one.pdf -o -name two.txt -o -name anotherone.jpg
```

`-o` or `-or` is logical OR. See [Finding Files on Gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Combining-Primaries-With-Operators) for more information.

I was running this on CygWin.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
cat $(file $( find . -readable) | grep ASCII | tr ":" " " | awk '{print $1}')
```

with that, you can find all readable files with ascii and read them with cat

if you want to specify his weight and no-executable:

```
cat $(file $( find . -readable ! -executable -size 1033c) | grep ASCII | tr ":" " " | awk '{print $1}')
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I forgot the space between the `(` and `-name`.

```
find . -not \(-name 'scripts' \)
```

Should have been

```
find . -not \( -name 'scripts' \)
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case i was missing trailing `/` in path.

```
find /var/opt/gitlab/backups/ -name *.tar
```

Comment: A trailing `/` is not required.