# BASH deletion script on file age

Tags: bash, find

I am a scripting novice.  I am trying to write a simple bash script for my Ubunutu 10.04 server to delete archives in a folder older than 30 days & older than a year in a different folder.  They can be two different command lines, as I will be putting them in different scripts.

I was just starting out by trying the following, which does not work at all:

```
# find ~/addon_backups/202 -name 202adata* -maxdepth 0 -ctime +30
```

and

```
# find ~/addon_backups/202/ME -name *.tar.gz -maxdepth 0 -ctime +365
```

I am getting the following respectively:

```
find: paths must precede expression: 202adata_010213.tar.gz
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

and

```
find: paths must precede expression: 0213ME-202.tar.gz
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

I have tried multiple variations and I am clearly missing something.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [This][1] seems to answer your question:


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495501/find-paths-must-precede-expression-how-do-i-specify-a-recursive-search-that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to quote the parameter to -name so the shell won't interpret it ([shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) automatically points that out):

```
find ~/addon_backups/202/ME -name "*.tar.gz" -maxdepth 0 -ctime +365
```

Also note that you'll want to use `-mtime` instead of `-ctime`, `-maxdepth 1` instead of 0, and you can use `-exec rm () {} +` to delete:

```
find ~/addon_backups/202/ME -name "*.tar.gz" -maxdepth 1 -mtime +365 -exec rm {} +
```

Or more simply:

```
find ~/addon_backups/202/ME/*.tar.gz -mtime +365 -exec rm {} +
```