# find: paths must precede expression

Tags: linux, shell, centos, centos6

I am using CentOS 6.4 final in two machines. I am executing a script. 
The script contains the `find` command

```
path=$1
searchstring=$2 
echo `find $path -name $searchString`
for filename in `find $path -name $searchString`
do
echo "$filename"
echo
done

./findfiles.sh /var/log/ *.txt
```

The above script is executing fine and printing the files. But in the second machine I am getting `usage error: find: paths must precede expression`

The reason behind is *.txt which got expanded in find command.After changing 
for filename in `find $path -name "$searchString"` 
it is executing fine.

Why syntax error is not happening in first CentOS machine?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495501/find-paths-must-precede-expression-how-do-i-specify-a-recursive-search-that

Comment: `find /path/to/find -type f -regex '.*\.\w\w\w'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quote your shell arguments:

```
$ ./findfiles.sh /var/log/ '*.txt'
```

Comment: Thanks Lutz!
I did the same and works fine. Still  i am confused about the behaviour of machines Thats why i have posted it.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use proper quoting or the shell will try to expand `*.txt` *before* `find` sees it.

So if the current folder contains `a.txt` and `b.txt`, then `find /var/log -name a.txt b.txt` will be executed -> `find` will be confused what you want to do with `b.txt`

That's why it's so important to use proper quoting. Your script should be:

```
path="$1"
searchstring="$2" 
echo $(find "$path" -name "$searchString")
for filename in $(find "$path" -name "$searchString")
do
    echo "$filename"
    echo
done
```

Note that I've quotes variable assignments (otherwise, the glob expansion will happen when you define `searchstring`. Same when you use the variables.

No quotes around `$()`! If you would add quotes there, then find would return a single "word" as result.

Also always prefer `$()` over the old inline-eval with back-ticks. It's much more reliable, less prone to subtle errors and more readable.