# find works in terminal but fails in bash script

Tags: regex, linux, bash

So I'm writing a bash script that counts the number of files in a directory and outputs a number. The function takes a directory argument as well as an optional file-type extension argument.

I am using the following lines to set the `dir` variable to the directory and `ext` variable to a regular expression that will represent all the file types to count.

```
dir=$1
[[ $# -eq 2 ]] && ext="*.$2" || ext="*"
```

The problem I am encountering occurs when I attempt to run the following line:

```
echo $(find $dir -maxdepth 1 -type f -name $ext | wc -l)
```

Running the script from the terminal works when I provide the second file-type argument but fails when I don't.

```
harrison@Luminous:~$ bash Documents/howmany.sh Documents/ sh
3
harrison@Luminous:~$ bash Documents/howmany.sh Documents/
find: paths must precede expression: Desktop
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
0
```

I have searched for this error and I know it's an issue with the shell expanding my wildcard as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495501/find-paths-must-precede-expression-how-do-i-specify-a-recursive-search-that). I've tried experimenting with single quotes, double quotes, and backslashes to escape the asterisk but nothing seems to work. What's particularly interesting is that when I try running this directly through the terminal, it works perfectly fine.

```
harrison@Luminous:~$ echo $(find Documents/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*" | wc -l)
6
```

Comment: hm, that worked for me in a bash script when I switched "Documents" with one in my cwd

Comment: You need to quote `"$dir"` in the find command. Probably `"$ext"` too. Also there is **literally** no reason to wrap that `find` command in `echo $(...)`.

Comment: @jm666 If you want find to output in one line then use `-printf` to tell it to do that. Don't abuse the shell's whitespace handling for that. But yes, there are certainly times when the shell's behaviour can be used intentionally.

Comment: BTW, next time you want to know why your script isn't behaving the same way as something you'd run on the command line, run `bash -x yourscript arg1 arg2 ...`, and see what it emits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplified:

```
dir=${1:-.}           #if $1 not set use .
name=${2+*.$2}        #if $2 is set use *.$2 for name
name=${name:-*}       #if name still isnt set, use *

find "$dir" -name "$name" -print   #use quotes
```

or

```
name=${2+*.$2}        #if $2 is set use *.$2 for name
find "${1:-.}" -name "${name:-*}" -print   #use quotes
```

also, as @John Kugelman says, you could use:

```
 name=${2+*.$2}
 find "${1:-.}" ${name:+-name "$name"} -print
```

`find . -name "*" -print` is the same as `find . -print`, so if `$name` isn't set, there's no need to specify `-name "*"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dir="$1"
[[ $# -eq 2 ]] && ext='*.$2' || ext='*'
```

If that doesn't work, you can just switch to an `if` statement, where you use the `-name` pattern in a branch and you don't in the other.

A couple more points:

- Those are not *regular expressions*, but rather *shell patterns*.
- *echo $(command)* is just equivalent to *command*.

Comment: Shouldn't change anything since `*` is not expanded in double quotes and word-splitting does not occur on the right side of assignment. He does need quotes in the `find`/`echo` as @EtanReisner pointed out in comments. Good points at the end.

Comment: Indeed, the quoting on those assignment lines is not the issue. The use of those variables is. But the other points are good.

Comment: Fine, I wasn't sure that would be effective, that's why I said "try" :).