# find: paths must precede expression: `days'

Tags: linux, find

Hi maybe a noob question here. I am running the command

`find . -atime -2 days # n = 2`

to see the files accessed 2 days ago. But the shell returns an error saying

`find: paths must precede expression:` days'`

I am using Ubuntu 20 LTS and cannot seem to understand the issue

I used the commands from [here](https://pieces-of-code.com/en/guide/howto/linux-find-by-date.html#find-date-related-test). And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495501/find-paths-must-precede-expression-how-do-i-specify-a-recursive-search-that) but cannot seem to solve my issue.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try removing `days` from the command. As per [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#index-_002datime) `atime` expects range in format `-n` or `+n`.

Comment: Please re-read the guidance for the tags you've used.  This is clearly a question about _using_ the `find` program, not about __programming__, so is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  It _might_ be suitable for [su]; consult the Help Centre for the site before you post.

Comment: Are all the questions off topic for Stack Overflow? Meaning just ignore SO and post on Super User. Because I have to use this command in _bash script_ which is related to programming I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate problem is that `-atime -2 days` is interpreted as the option `-atime` with the value `-2` and a path for `find` to search, which is an error because the paths need to be before the predicates on the command line.

The immediate fix is to remove "days" entirely, since the value for `-atime` is already expressed in units of days (or, strictly speaking, periods of 86400 seconds).

Some other commands allow you to express suffixes to indicate periods of time, but `find` is not one of them; but even then, they have to be quoted as a single argument. For example, `date -d "2 days"` (not `date -d 2 days`; and note that the `-d` option is a GNU extension, and not portable).

Unfortunately, the world wide web is saturated with "computer help" pages with syntax errors or worse, especially around shell scripting. If you find that an example doesn't work, probably consult the manual page for the utility you are trying to use.